# Misinterpreted grammar

Tags: xtext

I have the following grammar piece:

```
SlotConstraint:
  lExpr = [Slot] pred = ('in' | 'inn' | 'from' | 'fromm' | 'is')  rExpr = SetSexpr |
  lExpr = [Slot] pred = ('in' | 'inn' | 'from' | 'fromm' | 'is')? neg = ('not' | 'not in' | 'not from') rExpr = SetSexpr
;
```

When I write something like this - `a in b` or `a is not in b` it is fine. However I am not able to write `a is not b`. The question is: why it understands `not in` or `not from` but not plain `not`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use whitespace in keywords